# Enviar E-mail asp.net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

boa tarde pessoal, preciso de uma ajuda, não sei se estou fazendo errado mais quando tento enviar um e-mail, através código no controller nada acontece, podem me dar uma ajuda do que possa estar acorrendo de errado? não gera nenhum erro simplesmente não chaga e-mail no destinatário...se conseguirem me dar essa força fico agradecido

```html
 public ActionResult SendEmail()
        {
            MailMessage objEmail = new MailMessage();
            //rementente do email
            objEmail.From = new MailAddress("exemplo@outlook.com.br");

            //email para resposta(quando o destinatário receber e clicar em responder, vai para:)
            //objEmail.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("email@seusite.com.br");

            //destinatário(s) do email(s). Obs. pode ser mais de um, pra isso basta repetir a linha
            //abaixo com outro endereço
            objEmail.To.Add("exemplo@outlook.com.br");

            //se quiser enviar uma cópia oculta pra alguém, utilize a linha abaixo:
           // objEmail.Bcc.Add("oculto@provedor.com.br");

            //prioridade do email
            objEmail.Priority = MailPriority.High;

            //utilize true pra ativar html no conteúdo do email, ou false, para somente texto
            objEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            //Assunto do email
            objEmail.Subject = "Assunto";

            //corpo do email a ser enviado
            objEmail.Body = "Conteúdo do email. Se ativar html, pode utilizar cores, fontes, etc.";

            //codificação do assunto do email para que os caracteres acentuados serem reconhecidos.
            objEmail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

            //codificação do corpo do emailpara que os caracteres acentuados serem reconhecidos.
            objEmail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

            //cria o objeto responsável pelo envio do email
            SmtpClient objSmtp = new SmtpClient();

            //endereço do servidor SMTP(para mais detalhes leia abaixo do código)
            objSmtp.Host = "SMTP.office365.com";
            objSmtp.Port = 587;

                     //para envio de email autenticado, coloque login e senha de seu servidor de email
                     //para detalhes leia abaixo do código
            objSmtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("exemplo.com.br", "senha");

            //envia o email
            objSmtp.Send(objEmail);
            return View("Index");
        }
```

Comment: Já tentou ativar o ssl? `objSmtp.EnableSsl = true;` Segundo essa documentação, é necessário: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pop-and-imap-email-settings-for-outlook-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353

Comment: cara show, funcionou, muito obrigado

Comment: Não esqueça de aceitar a resposta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação do Office365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pop-and-imap-email-settings-for-outlook-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353), para fazer uso do servidor SMTP é necessário ativar a criptografia `STARTTLS`.

> IMAP Server: outlook.office365.com Port: 993 Encryption: SSL/TLS
>
> POP Server: outlook.office365.com Port: 995 Encryption: SSL/TLS
>
> SMTP Server: smtp.office365.com Port: 587 Encryption: STARTTLS

Para fazer isso no código apresentado, basta adicionar `objSmtp.EnableSsl = true;` antes de `objSmtp.Send(objEmail);`.